# VS Code / Errors during Python package Installation with pip / Capytaine package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, pip

I am trying to install the capytaine package using pip (`pip install capytaine`) (in VS Code).
Unfortunately I am getting multiple errors, although other packages such as numpy, matplotlib etc. are installed and run successfully. I have beginner to intermediate python and general programming skills, however I struggle solving delicate issues, such as dealing with errors I encountered here. Therefore, I am not sure whether the errors are caused by wheel, setup.py or some path related mistake.
I have already went through some other discussions, but couldn't find a useful resource for my problem, neither has installing C++ build tools recommended by VS Code helped.

I've got Python 3.9.13, wheel 0.37.1 and setuptools 65.3.0 on my computer. (Should I downgrade setuptools to below 60 version? how?)

I would really appreciate if you could assist me resolve the installation issues here.

I've cropped the irrelevant parts of the output after running `pip install capytaine` to fit
the character requirements, hope it's not gibberish.

```
PS D:\TUHH\Master\Masterarbeit\Preliminary_tests\NemohAQWA_Check> pip install capytaine
Collecting capytaine
  Using cached capytaine-1.4.tar.gz (124 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\dodob\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from capytaine) (1.23.2)
.
.
.

Building wheels for collected packages: capytaine
  Building wheel for capytaine (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [213 lines of output]
      C:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-46g3rmya\capytaine_cc3bdd35637b4ed48d97c88363dfe438\setup.py:9: DeprecationWarning:
      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
        from numpy.distutils.core import Extension, setup
      running bdist_wheel
.
.
.

 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\capytaine\green_functions\Delhommeau_f90module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\capytaine\green_functions\Delhommeau_f90module.obj -O2 -fopenmp -cpp
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-cpp'
      Delhommeau_f90module.c
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\capytaine\green_functions -IC:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.316"
.
.
.

  INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-46g3rmya\capytaine_cc3bdd35637b4ed48d97c88363dfe438\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for capytaine
  Running setup.py clean for capytaine
Failed to build capytaine
Installing collected packages: capytaine
  Running setup.py install for capytaine ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for capytaine did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [200 lines of output]
      C:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-46g3rmya\capytaine_cc3bdd35637b4ed48d97c88363dfe438\setup.py:9: DeprecationWarning:
     
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
     
     
        from numpy.distutils.core import Extension, setup
      running install
      C:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
.
.
.

 creating C:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpv6hwqlsf\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\distutils\checks
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1073] : testing flags (/WX)
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1240] : feature 'AVX512_KNL' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1240] : feature 'AVX512_KNM' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1782] : check requested baseline
.
.
.

  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\capytaine\green_functions -IC:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\capytaine\green_functions\Delhommeau_f90module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\capytaine\green_functions\Delhommeau_f90module.obj -O2 -fopenmp -cpp" failed with exit status 2
      INFO:
      ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      INFO: Platform      :
        Architecture: x64
        Compiler    : msvc
     
      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : none
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none
     
      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : none
        Generated   : none
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\dodob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-46g3rmya\capytaine_cc3bdd35637b4ed48d97c88363dfe438\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> capytaine

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Try to install using the following command in conda environment: `conda install -c conda-forge capytaine`.

Comment: Read [docs](https://github.com/capytaine/capytaine#installation), it can ONLY be installed in conda environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/capytaine/capytaine#installation).

This package can only be installed by `Conda package manager` by the following codes:

```
conda install -c conda-forge capytaine
```

You need to create an conda environment then install this package.

The Python extension automatically detects existing conda environments. We recommend you install a Python interpreter into your conda environment, otherwise one will be installed for you after you select the environment. For example, the following command creates a conda environment with the Python 3.9 interpreter and several libraries, which VS Code then shows in the list of available interpreters:

```
conda create -n env-01 python=3.9 scipy=0.15.0 astroid babel
```

You can refer to [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-conda-environment) for more details to create a conda environment.

Comment: There are still some minor issues, but basically yes. `conda install -c conda-forge capytaine` solved the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One way is If you install a new version of python make sure you have added the path into the System environment variable of windows.

The second one is In VS code you need to add a Python Interpreter to run a pip command.

###### a. CTRL+SHIFT+P to open Command Palette.

###### b. Type & Select Python Interpreter in Command Palette.

The third way is to create a virtual environment and activate it in your project and run any types of pip command you want to install.
For that see the
link 1 (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)
Link 2 (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a conflict of package versions. Try running `pip list`, copying all of your packages, creating a new file called `requirements.txt`, putting all of your packages in there (without versions) and running `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This will tell pip to solve the version conflict and you'll get a more readable error in the worst case scenario.